# ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point

Tags: python-3.x, flask, geopy

i want to pass my latitude and langitude values to my flask route but everytime i am getting this error: **ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point**

however i have tried this and its working fine:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template 
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


app = Flask(__name__)

geolocator = Nominatim()



@app.route('/location')
def lang_and_lat():
    location = geolocator.reverse("21.0943, 81.0337")

    address = location.address

    return render_template('ip.html', address=address)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template 
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


app = Flask(__name__)

geolocator = Nominatim()



@app.route('/location/<lat>/<lang>')
def lang_and_lat(lat, lang):
    location = geolocator.reverse(lat, lang)

    address = location.address

    return render_template('ip.html', address=address)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: in the first snippet you pass one positional argument of type `str` which represent latitude and longitude separated by comma, while in the second you pass 2 positional arguments of type `str`.

Comment: i want to pass latitude and longitude values as arguments to my flask route

Comment: You are calling a function in an API.  You can't just pass the values the way you want; you have to pass them in a way that the API function is prepared to accept them.  All examples I've seen of geolocator.reverse take a string with the two values separated by a comma.  The error message you are getting indicates that you should be able to put the two values together in a Point object and pass that, but I have not seen any such examples.

Comment: Then do so, but then join them in single `str` as expected by `geolocator.reverse()`

Comment: I found  this: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/93521/geopy.Point, which shows how to create a geopy.Point object: origin = geopy.Point(latitude=lat, longitude=lon)

Comment: @buran thanks for  the suggestion. I'll try that

Answer (score 3):

you need to do
`location = geolocator.reverse(f'{lat}, {lang}')`

or 
`location = geolocator.reverse(Point(lat, lang))`
in second case you need to `from geopy.point import Point`

Comment: you're too fast for me :-)

Comment: @vatsalay, if this solve your problem, look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you very much @buran! :)